# USB Host initialization (controlTransfer) for PIC24 Microcontroller

Tags: android, usb, microcontroller, host, pic24

I am working on an application that utilizes the **USB Host capabilities of Android to communicate with a micro controller based device (PIC24FJ64GB002)**. The device has Microchip's USB stack on it and has been confirmed to work through testing with windows. I am now trying to establish communication with the device through the Android application. So far I have been able to detect the device (through an intent filter in the manifest file), open device and claim the control interface (interface 0). I know that I need to perform some initialization/setup of the device but I am not sure how to do this. For instance, I know that for the Arduino USB-to-Serial it is...

```
conn.controlTransfer(0x21, 34, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);
        conn.controlTransfer(0x21, 32, 0, 0, new byte[] { (byte) 0x80,
                0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08 }, 7, 0);
```

and for the FTDI based Arduinos it is...

```
conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);// reset
conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 1, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Rx
conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 2, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Tx
conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x03, 0x4138, 0, null, 0, 0);
```

But I do not know how to set up the Microchip USB Stack on the PIC24. The code that I have so far is shown below... Thanks

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    private static final int VID = 0x04D8;
    private static final int PID = 0x000A;
    public static int temperature;
    public static int humidity;
    public static int lpg;
    public static int alcohol;
    ListView listView;

    //USB   
    UsbDevice USBDevice_s;
    UsbDeviceConnection USBDeviceConnection_s;
    UsbEndpoint USBEndpoint_s;
    UsbInterface USBInterface_s;
    UsbManager USBManager_s;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Model.LoadModel();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] ids = new String[Model.Items.size()];
        for (int i= 0; i < ids.length; i++)
        {

            ids[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);
        }

        ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row, ids);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        //Begin USB process after layout has been configured...

        USBManager_s = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = USBManager_s.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();

        while(deviceIterator.hasNext())
        {
            USBDevice_s = deviceIterator.next();
        }

        Intent Intent_s = getIntent();
        String action = Intent_s.getAction();
        USBDevice_s = (UsbDevice) Intent_s.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        //If device is attached
        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action))
        {
            USBInterface_s = USBDevice_s.getInterface(0);
            USBEndpoint_s = USBInterface_s.getEndpoint(0);
            USBDeviceConnection_s = USBManager_s.openDevice(USBDevice_s);
            USBDeviceConnection_s.claimInterface(USBInterface_s,  true);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Value of device :" +USBDevice_s.getDeviceName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (USBDeviceConnection_s != null && USBDeviceConnection_s.claimInterface(USBInterface_s, true))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Device Open, Interface Claimed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (USBDeviceConnection_s != null)
            {
                //Perform setup/initialization.....
            }

        }

        //If device is detached
        else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) 
        {
            USBDevice_s = (UsbDevice) Intent_s.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (USBDevice_s != null) 
            {
                USBDeviceConnection_s = USBManager_s.openDevice(USBDevice_s);
                USBDeviceConnection_s.releaseInterface(USBInterface_s);
                USBDeviceConnection_s.close();              
                Toast.makeText(this,"Device Removed, Interface Released", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }



        //Update Layout
        temperature = 1; humidity = 63; lpg = 5000; alcohol = 500;
        Model.LoadModel();
        ItemAdapter adapter2 = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row, ids);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter2);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_settings:
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Exiting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
           // .show();
        //finish();
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }

      return true;
    }

}
```

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.byrdonatwigge.sense"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.byrdonatwigge.sense.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                       android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"
                       android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**device_filter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="1240" product-id="10" />
</resources>
```